# "Enable AJAX add to cart buttons on archives" is not working

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce latest version. I am developing a woocommerce supported theme from the scratch. Now I have a little problem. On archive page Ajax for "Add to cart" button is not working. Whenever I click "Add to cart" button the page get reloaded. I check the product setting and I got the "Enable AJAX add to cart buttons on archives " is checked. But the ajax is still not working. So where is the bug?

Note: I am a new bee  in woocommerce type work.

Answer (score 0):

The page being reloaded doesn't mean it's not added to the cart. You'll need to check `/cart` to verify if your product is added. 
If you want to cart redirect after successful addition. I believe this is the setting right where the archive ajax cart setting is.

Comment: Tread There is no problem with adding to the cart. I have checked already, the product I click goes to the cart. But I don't want the page being reloaded. I want to prevent this page reloaded.

Comment: I think its just default behavior. Like I mentioned in the answer, you have  another setting to have it redirect to the cart.